# How to parse from this JSONString?

Tags: java, android, json, http

I get the below `JSONString` through `HTTP Request`. And I want all `amount` values from this String.

**I tried this so far:**

```
try {
    // Getting JSON Array
    JSONArray spritPriceArr = jObj.getJSONArray("spritPrice");

    int spritPriceArrLength = spritPriceArr.length();
    for(int i=0; i < spritPriceArrLength; i++ ){

    JSONObject c = spritPriceArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String amount = c.getString("amount");

    System.out.println(amount);
     }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works for the first `spritPrice Array`. But how can I get the `amounts` of the other `spritPrice Array` ?

I really dont know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me please.

This is a link to my full JSON String:  [>>This<<](http://www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B%22%22,%22DIE%22,12.949586663166395,48.19435760497557,13.084464736833604,48.28482259502443%5D)

[{"kredit":true,"self":false,**"spritPrice"**:[{**"amount"**:"1.329","datAnounce":"2013-11-27 13:05:07","errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"datValid":1385553907000,"spritId":"DIE"}],"automat":true,"city":"Braunau","open":true,"distance":2.21,"postalCode":"5280","errorItems":[],"priceSearchDisabled":false,"longitude":"13.0365064","payMethod":"Routex","mail":"","gasStationName":"BP","fax":"","clubCard":"","openingHours":[{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Sonntag","order":7,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"SO"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Mittwoch","order":3,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"MI"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Feiertag","order":8,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"FE"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Montag","order":1,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"MO"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Donnerstag","order":4,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"DO"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Freitag","order":5,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"FR"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Samstag","order":6,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"SA"},"end":"22:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Dienstag","order":2,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"DI"},"end":"22:00"}],"access":"","url":"","serviceText":"gratis Staubsaugen","maestro":true,"companionship":false,"address":"Salzburger Str. 11","club":false,"errorCode":1,"service":false,"latitude":"48.2546591","bar":true,"telephone":""},{"kredit":true,"self":false,**"spritPrice"**:[{**"amount**":"1.334","datAnounce":"2013-11-27 12:40:18","errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"datValid":1385552418000,"spritId":"DIE"}],"automat":true,"city":"Braunau","open":true,"distance":2.42,"postalCode":"5280","errorItems":[],"priceSearchDisabled":false,"longitude":"13.048711","payMethod":"Novofleet","mail":"office@fetrading.at","gasStationName":"FE-Trading GmbH ","fax":"4362467223611","clubCard":"","openingHours":[{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Montag","order":1,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"MO"},"end":"21:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Donnerstag","order":4,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"DO"},"end":"21:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Dienstag","order":2,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"DI"},"end":"21:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Samstag","order":6,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"SA"},"end":"21:00"},{"beginn":"08:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Sonntag","order":7,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"SO"},"end":"18:00"},{"beginn":"08:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Feiertag","order":8,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"FE"},"end":"18:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Freitag","order":5,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"FR"},"end":"21:00"},{"beginn":"06:00","day":{"dayLabel":"Mittwoch","order":3,"errorItems":[],"errorCode":0,"day":"MI"},"end":"21:00"}],"access":"","url":"http://www.fe-trading.at","serviceText":"","maestro":true,"companionship":false,"address":"Hofer Straße 1 (\" Hofer Parkplatz\")","club":false,"errorCode":1,"service":false,"latitude":"48.244911","bar":false,"telephone":"4362467223634"}]

Comment: i only able to give a reference to how u do this

Comment: yes please. would be great

Comment: you are posting wrong JSON response .Update your JSON string

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
Check this tutorial for refrence

Comment: no this is what I really get. Its only a longer String with more spritPrices. But this is it.

Comment: First format your code properly so that one can understand.

Comment: this is not my code this is my Json String what I retrieve from HTTP Response. And this i cant format in a better way

Comment: Look at this link: this is my hole JSON String .. http://www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B%22%22,%22DIE%22,12.949586663166395,48.19435760497557,13.084464736833604,48.28482259502443%5D

Comment: use JSON View extension for chrome and then see your json string. you must access the `[0].spritPrice[0].amount  and [1].spritPrice[0].amount ...` but you are accessing first array only.`[0].spritPrice[0].amount  and [0].spritPrice[1].amount`. so you are not getting the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
// ArrayList<String> amountList=new ArrayList<String>();
  String amount=null;
 try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            String your_json_response;
            JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(your_json_response);
            for(int j=0;j<responseArray.length();j++)
            {
                JSONArray spritPrice=responseArray.getJSONObject(i).JSONArray("spritPrice");

                int spritPrice= spritPrice.length();

                for(int i=0; i < spritPrice; i++ ){

                  JSONObject c = spritPrice.getJSONObject(i);

                     amount = c.getString("amount");
                     // amountList.add(amount); 
                      System.out.println(amount);
                       if(amount!=null)
                          break;
                    }
                    if(amount!=null)
                      break;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: It gives me 10 times the first price.

Comment: nice. I changed something. Now it's working. I edit your post and then I accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
try{
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);
for(int i = 0; i< json.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject c1 = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
    JSONArray spritPrice = c1.getJSONArray("spritPrice");
    for (int j = 0; j < spritPrice.length(); j++)
    {
        JSONObject c2 = (JSONObject) spritPrice.get(j);
        String amount = c2.getString("amount");
        System.out.println(amount);
    }
}}catch (JSONException e){
e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just taking String,also take ArrayList or List and add each price.

Like this,

```
 ArrayList<String> prices=new ArrayList<String>
```

Write below code inside your loop.

```
 String amount = c.getString("amount");
 prices.add(amount);
```

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Later you can access all the prices from ArrayList.for e.g String price1=prices.get(0); String price2=prices.get(1);

Comment: But it is still only the first price

Comment: Later you can access all the prices from ArrayList.for e.g String price1=prices.get(0); String price2=prices.get(1);

Comment: no. there is just only the first price. the loop end at the first `spritPrice`

Comment: actually there is problem with your json.It is Nested array.And also there is no name given to outer array.inner array is spritPrice

Comment: Look at this example of json.your json should be like this!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get strings from jsonarray, try to do it:

```
try {
  JSONArray spritPriceArr = jObj.getJSONArray("spritPrice");
  int spritPriceArrLength = spritPriceArr.length();
  String[] StringofAmount = new Strng[spritPriceArrLength]
  for(int i=0; i < spritPriceArrLength; i++ ){
    JSONObject c = spritPriceArr.getJSONObject(i);
    StringofAmount[i] = c.optString("amount");
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
public void loadAmountFrom(String jsonArrayString) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
        loadAmountFromJsonArray(jsonArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

private void loadAmountFromJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Object object = jsonArray.get(i);
            if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
                loadAmountFromJsonArray(jsonArray);
            } else if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                loadAmount(jsonObject);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

private void loadAmount(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            if(key.equals("amount")) {
                Object object = jsonObject.get(key);
                arrayList.add(object.toString());
            } else {
                Object object = jsonObject.get(key);
                if(object instanceof JSONArray) {
                    loadAmountFromJsonArray((JSONArray) object);
                } else if(object instanceof JSONObject) {
                    loadAmount((JSONObject) object);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

just pass String response to loadAmountFrom(String) method...

Answer (score 0):

Your array `spritPrice` is of length 1:

```
  "spritPrice":[
     {
        "amount":"1.329",
        "datAnounce":"2013-11-27 13:05:07",
        "errorItems":[

        ],
        "errorCode":0,
        "datValid":1385553907000,
        "spritId":"DIE"
     }
  ],
```

Your root element must be `JSONArray`, not `JSONObject`.

A good link: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It shows that your JSON is an array.

```
[
   {
      "kredit":true,
      "self":false,
      "spritPrice":[
     {
        "amount":"1.329",
        "datAnounce":"2013-11-27 13:05:07",
        "errorItems":[

        ],
        "errorCode":0,
        "datValid":1385553907000,
        "spritId":"DIE"
     }
      ],
      "automat":true,
      "city":"Braunau",
      "open":true,
      "distance":2.21,
      "postalCode":"5280",
      "errorItems":[

      ],
      "priceSearchDisabled":false,
      "longitude":"13.0365064",
      "payMethod":"Routex",
      "mail":"",
      "gasStationName":"BP",
      "fax":"",
      "clubCard":"",
      "openingHours":[
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Sonntag",
           "order":7,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"SO"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Mittwoch",
           "order":3,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"MI"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Feiertag",
           "order":8,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"FE"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Montag",
           "order":1,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"MO"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Donnerstag",
           "order":4,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"DO"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Freitag",
           "order":5,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"FR"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Samstag",
           "order":6,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"SA"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Dienstag",
           "order":2,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"DI"
        },
        "end":"22:00"
     }
      ],
      "access":"",
      "url":"",
      "serviceText":"gratis Staubsaugen",
      "maestro":true,
      "companionship":false,
      "address":"Salzburger Str. 11",
      "club":false,
      "errorCode":1,
      "service":false,
      "latitude":"48.2546591",
      "bar":true,
      "telephone":""
   },
   {
      "kredit":true,
      "self":false,
      "spritPrice":[
     {
        "amount":"1.334",
        "datAnounce":"2013-11-27 12:40:18",
        "errorItems":[

        ],
        "errorCode":0,
        "datValid":1385552418000,
        "spritId":"DIE"
     }
      ],
      "automat":true,
      "city":"Braunau",
      "open":true,
      "distance":2.42,
      "postalCode":"5280",
      "errorItems":[

      ],
      "priceSearchDisabled":false,
      "longitude":"13.048711",
      "payMethod":"Novofleet",
      "mail":"office@fetrading.at",
      "gasStationName":"FE-Trading GmbH ",
      "fax":"4362467223611",
      "clubCard":"",
      "openingHours":[
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Montag",
           "order":1,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"MO"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Donnerstag",
           "order":4,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"DO"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Dienstag",
           "order":2,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"DI"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Samstag",
           "order":6,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"SA"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"08:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Sonntag",
           "order":7,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"SO"
        },
        "end":"18:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"08:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Feiertag",
           "order":8,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"FE"
        },
        "end":"18:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Freitag",
           "order":5,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"FR"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     },
     {
        "beginn":"06:00",
        "day":{
           "dayLabel":"Mittwoch",
           "order":3,
           "errorItems":[

           ],
           "errorCode":0,
           "day":"MI"
        },
        "end":"21:00"
     }
      ],
      "access":"",
      "url":"http://www.fe-trading.at",
      "serviceText":"",
      "maestro":true,
      "companionship":false,
      "address":"Hofer Straße 1 (\" Hofer Parkplatz\")",
      "club":false,
      "errorCode":1,
      "service":false,
      "latitude":"48.244911",
      "bar":false,
      "telephone":"4362467223634"
   }
]
```